# how to implement password recovery for a winform C# application

Tags: c#, passwords

I have a Winform application written in C# which is purely windows based. It doesn't have any web module, nor I have any web domain name registered. 
The software is complete but now I need to incorporate another functionality called the password recovery. I am new to this stuff, so please help me.
I dont wanna keep it hard. i just want that if a user forgets his password, all he does is that he presses 'forgot password?' hyperlink on the login screen and password should be e-mailed to him in his e-mail account.How do I achieve this functionality? Please give a code example considering that my e-mail is 'source@gmail.com' and destination e-mail is 'destination@gmail.com'

Comment: I don't mean to be sarcastic or anything, but if you completed some package and I am pretty sure there are some complex features involved, it's really hard to believe that such a simple thing as password recovery is a tough cookie for you!

Comment: Where were you wanting to keep the password? On the local machine? Also note that keeping the raw password is a bad idea, that's why most forgot password links send you a link to reset it, not to retrieve it. Google for one-way password encryption.

Comment: If you're storing it locally then emailing probably isn't as useful a mechanism as it is on the web. Just store the answers to some challenge questions and show the password if the user has the right answers (e.g. What's your fathers middle name)

Comment: Don't use passwords in a Winforms app, the OS login is much more reliable.

Comment: @HansPassant Normally true, but we shouldn't second guess the scenario. It could be a dumb terminal or shared pc in a warehouse somewhere for entering timesheets for all we know.

Comment: I think the way that's suggested by JRoughan is the one that I will use

Comment: @HuseinRoncevic, I was looking for an idea about how it is usually done by most winform applications. Now, after reading suggestions in replies, I believe that asking security questions and then showing the password would be a better way. But for this too, I need to change my application a bit, because right now, my passwords are stored as hashed passwords in the database and there is no utility to decode the password. For authentication, I just encode the password, and then compare it with the database value. I need to think of that.

Comment: You are better off having an email validation then redirect the user to create a new password.. even if you don't do it this suggested way this is not a hard task. good luck

Answer (score 2):

As user1932945 said you should never store the actual password. Instead, you should hash their password add a randomly generated number (your key) to the end of the password. Then hash the new password. Finally, store the hashed password along with the key. Then when they log in you take their password and get the key from wherever it's stored add it to the password again, hash it, then compare it against the hashed password you stored.

When they forget their password, you should email them with a way to reset their password. When they reset it you follow the steps I already mentioned to store the new password.

Comment: `+1 RandomlyKnighted` also, Perhaps the OP is in need of an example from you based on what you are suggesting

Answer (score 1):

You should never email a password to someone. This implies that you are storing the password, which you should never do. You should instead allow the user to reset their password.

The way to do this would be to email a code which would trigger a password reset in the winform app. The reset code could be a guid generated by the winform app upon request and stored in memory until the email has been received.